# How to convert create-react-app to Preact?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, preact

As per Preact documentation, to convert a React app to Preact you have to alias webpack:

```
{
  "resolve": {
    "alias": {
      "react": "preact-compat",
      "react-dom": "preact-compat"
    }
  }
}
```

How can you do this with `create-react-app` since that hides webpack under react-scripts dependency?

Thank you!

Comment: I guess you would have to eject as this config go in webpack. If you are getting started they recommend using `preact-cli` to get the project started

Comment: @Rikin Thank you! I think eject is not an option, as that would bring everything inside my project and make it non-upgradable. But preact-cli is interesting option, hope it'll support react components via preact-compact.

Answer (score 8):

I think the most elegant solution is to use [`customize-cra`](https://github.com/arackaf/customize-cra). This way you can avoid ejecting or maintaining a separate fork of `create-react-app`.

- First, you need to install `customize-cra`:

```
yarn add customize-cra react-app-rewired --D
```

- Then, go to `package.json`, change your `scripts` to the following (this step is crucial but is not explicitly mentioned in `customize-cra`'s docs):

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

- Go to the root of your project, create a file called `config-overrides.js` with the following content (assuming you're using Preact X):

```js
const { override, addWebpackAlias } = require('customize-cra');

module.exports = override(
  addWebpackAlias({
    'react': 'preact/compat',
    'react-dom': 'preact/compat'
  })
);
```

- Run `yarn start`... And Voila!

Comment: I used [craco](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco) to override CRA, and it works, thx !!

Comment: Fair warning, customize-cra last update as of writing this comment is 7 months ago and react-scripts 4.0.0 had been released for quite some time which breaks this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can get it working with **craco**:

```js
// craco.config.js
module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    alias: {
      "react": "preact/compat",
      "react-dom": "preact/compat"
    }
  }
}
```

**Note: Do not uninstall `react`, `@types/react`, or `@types/react-dom` after adding `preact`!**

`react` is still required by `react-scripts` to run `craco start` and friends.

`@types/*` are still required by your IDE for type suggestions.

**Note: Bundle analyzers [may still report that you're using React](https://github.com/preactjs/preact/discussions/3048)!**

Make sure to double-check your output directory for real build sizes.

Comment: Does anybody know how to remove react (as we have preact now) in order to optimize bundle size?

Comment: @AnatoliiOlshevskyi Can I ask why you think React is still in your bundle?

Comment: Because when I remove it from my package.json I've got "Error: Cannot find module 'react'" during yarn start. That probably means react scripts require react for some reason as dependency.

Comment: @AnatoliiOlshevskyi `react-scripts` still needs `react` to start/build/etc, but in my testing it wasn't included in my production bundle.